# Gravitational potential energy of a coupled pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve problem a problem of complete energy of doubled  pendulum (2 mathematical pendulums connected by a string).

For a kinetic energy I would get $\frac{1}{2}$J $\dot{x_1}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$J $\dot{x_2}$ (kinetic energy of a first pendulum + second pendulum).

For the potential energy of a spring I get naturally $\frac{1}{2}$k ($x_1-x_2$)$^2$.

What about gravitational potential energy of pendulum 1 and pendulum 2? I get really stuck here. How can I write it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Assuming the spring is massless, wouldn't it just be $m_1gx_1+m_2gx_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Connected by a string or a spring?

Let $\theta$ be the angle of the first pendulum rod and vertical, and $\phi$ be the angle between the second pendulum rod and vertical.  These are your free variables.

Let $l_1, l_2$ be the length of the pendulum rods.

Potential energy $m_1g (\Delta h_1) + m_2 g (\Delta h_2).$

Where $\Delta h_1, \Delta h_2$ are the lowest points that the two masses can be at (or when the system is at rest)

$\Delta h_1 = l_1 (1-\sin\theta)\\
\Delta h_2 = \Delta h_1 + l_2(1-\sin\phi)$

$v_1 = l_1(\cos\theta, -\sin\theta) \ d\theta\\
v_2 = v_1 + l_2(\cos\phi, -\sin\phi) \ d\phi$

Kinnetic engery $= \frac 12 m_1 \|v_1\|^2 + \frac 12 m_2 \|v_2\|^2\\
\frac 12 ((m_1+m_2) l_1^2 (d\theta)^2 + m_2 l_2^2 (d\phi)^2 + 2m_2(l_1l_2)(\cos(\theta-\phi)(d\theta)(d\phi))$